# How do programs accessing symbolic links differ from users? (What scenarios can break by replacing a file with a symbolic link?)

Tags: files, symlink, programming

I think I understand what soft and hard symbolic links are, but I'm not sure how programs access them (as opposed to me, a user).

For example, I want to replace my ~/.bashrc with a symbolic link that resides elsewhere. When I as a *user* open this file, say in Vim, really I'm editing ~/some/path/.bashrc (regardless the type of link). That's good and all, but what about programs? For example an installer that appends to ~/.bashrc?

1. Can programs open a file in either "mode"—following a symlink or not? My guess is that *file handles* in programming languages compile or interpret such that they refer to an inode, so with hardlinks at least, they always follow.
2. If softlinks *can* be opened in either mode, what does that look like in a major programming language?
3. If programs are "blind" to symbolic links, then is it safe to assume I can softlink ~/.bashrc to ~/some/path/.bashrc and expect it to work with no hitches ever, provided that the file exists and retains the same permissions as the original ~/.bashrc? Or is there some weird scenario that *can* break its function?

I have read

- [How to efficiently track .bashrc (and similar) with git?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516071/49062) (No answer.)
- [Are there pitfalls to putting $HOME in git instead of symlinking dotfiles?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46538/49062) (I don't want this setup.)

and other answers that explain the difference between a soft and hardlink, but more knowledge about symbolic links doesn't make me feel confident in this regard.

Comment: a common method of "atomic write" is writing to a temporary file then moving it, overwriting the destination (which would break a symlink)

Comment: @Fox - Ah, so actually that's what `git pull` would do too, so either direction of symlinking would break when pulling down a remote change, if I'm correct. I guess then there can't be a solution that doesn't re-create those links (_e.g._ via a git hook). I'm still curious about how languages handle files though, so keeping this question open.

Comment: Many editors do that too...

Comment: Many "security" type programs regard soft links of configuration files as an attempt to deceive. Hard links are just a counter in an inode. Finding out the other  hardlinks is difficult.